# Autotools configure.ac/Makefile.am install directory

Tags: autotools

I'm building a plugin for asterisk, with libtool, I would like to install the plugin in a specific directory ("$(libdir)/asterisk/modules") but it always install the module in "/usr/lib//"... does anyone knows how to set the install directory for such a plugin?

in [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Hard_002dCoded-Install-Paths.html) they are talking about installing a plugin for other packages, but just talking about finding install path... not setting it.

Maybe I didn't search the good terms... but googling a little this subject only gives answers using "./configure" options... nothing about forcing install path...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a directory where the module should be installed, like this:

```
plugindir = $(libdir)/asterisk/modules
plugin_LTLIBRARIES = yourplugin.la
```

You may have to figure out the right plugindir by calling `pkg-config`, but that's a question for another time.

Answer (score -1):

So I would like to submit some piece of answer : 
using "lib_LTLIBRARIES" installs library into $(libdir)
using "pkglib_LTLIBRARIES" installs library into $(libdir)/pkgname
so I tried to use "lib_asterisk_modules_LTLIBRARIES" (wich makes automake complains about missing variable "lib_asterisk_modulesdir") and it seems to install it into "$(libdir)/asterisk/modules"

If it can help anyone.